# set the focus to a textbox with a htmleditorextendor inside an update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, datalist, htmleditorextender

i have a textbox attached to a htmleditorextender that is present inside a usercontrol and this user control is present inside a data list control which is  in  an update panel. i have a edit link button on click of which the text box is shown and at this time i want to set focus to the text box i have tried doing this.

```
 protected void lnkEditResponse_OnCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (QuestionList.Items.Count == 0)
        {
            log.Warn("There are no items in the data list.");
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            DataListItem item = QuestionList.Items[int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString())];
            if (item == null)
            {
                log.Warn("No item found for the index " + e.CommandArgument);
                return;
            }

            Panel responseLabelPanel = item.FindControl("ResponseLabelPanel") as Panel;
            Panel responseInputPanel = item.FindControl("ResponseInputPanel") as Panel;
            TextBox textArea = item.FindControl("QuestionResponseTextBox") as TextBox;
            responseLabelPanel.Visible = false;
            responseInputPanel.Visible = true;

            ScriptManager mgr = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);                                


            (responseInputPanel.FindControl("LinkClearAll") as LinkButton).Visible = true;
            (responseInputPanel.FindControl("lnkClear") as LinkButton).Visible = true;
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "f", "document.getElementById('" + textArea.ClientID + "').focus();", true);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("Exception while handling file delete.", ex);
        }
    }
```

i have also tried getting the texbox and doing .Focus() but its not working is there some way of getting this done. 
PS: its very important that i set the focus to the end of the currently present text in the text box (the text boxes are loaded with data from the data base)

Answer (score 0):

Use client side script to focus. 
`HtmlEditorExtendor` Load many content in page. This may cause problem .
Try to use below jQuery may help you.

Eg:

```
$('#target').focus();
```